# Control inside DataGridTemplateColumn CellEditingTemplate doesn't update data source

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I'm implementing a dialog with mvvm pattern, where I have a datagrid bound to an observable collection of data objects.

The objects in my grid have two string properties, `DisplayedBarcode` and `InputBarcode`, that I need to display or display and edit in the same column, depending on a third boolean property called `IsBarcodeEditable`.
Here's a code sample from my data model:

```
    public class DataObject : ViewModelBase
    {

        #region Fields

        private string _barcode;
        private string _inputBarcode;


        #endregion

        #region Properties

        /// <summary>
        /// A bool specifying whether the barcode field is editable
        /// </summary>

        public bool IsBarcodeEditable { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// A string from a user input representing a manually entered barcode
        /// </summary>
        public string InputBarcode
        {
            get { return _inputBarcode; }
            set
            {                
                
                if (_inputBarcode == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _inputBarcode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(InputBarcode));
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// A string representing an automatically read barcode
        /// </summary>
        public string DisplayedBarcode
        {
            get { return _barcode; }
            set
            {
                if (_barcode == value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _barcode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DisplayedBarcode));
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

A template column with a CellTemplate and a CellEditingTemplate should allow me to display data from one binding, while editing from another binding, like in the implementation below:

```
            <DataGrid                
                ItemsSource="{Binding DataObjectCollection}"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                EnableRowVirtualization="False"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectionUnit="Cell"
                IsReadOnly="False"
                CanUserResizeRows="False"
                CanUserReorderColumns="False"
                CanUserSortColumns="True"
                CanUserAddRows="False">
                <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="0"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn
                            MinWidth="100"
                            Header="Barcode">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox
                                    Text="{Binding Path=DisplayedBarcode, Mode=OneWay}"/>                                    
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox 
                                    Text="{Binding Path=InputBarcode, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsBarcodeEditable}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

The problem is that the textbox (or any other control element) inside the CellEditingTemplate doesn't allow editing. I can type correctly inside the textbox in rows where `IsBarcodeEditable` is true, but the setter of the bound property `InputBarcode` is never called.
I already tried setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` but it did not help.

Through trial and error I found out that the property is updated correctly when I place my editing textbox inside a CellTemplate (i.e. the setter of the property is called correctly).
So, basically the CellTemplate behaves like I would expect a CellEditingTemplate to behave.
When switching DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate to DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate and vice versa in my code sample above, the grid behaves almost as needed, except that it doesn't display DisplayedBarcode any more, which is a requirement for me.

One way and two way binding to other normal DataGridTextColumns in my grid works as expected, so there's no general problem with the communication between model, view model and view.

What am I missing?

EDIT:
Thanks to mm8's question I realized that the text box in the cell template seems to hide the text box in the cell editing template, so that the user interacts with the former.

If the textbox in the celltemplate should be kept without interfering with the second textbox, the following modifications can be made:

```
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn
                            MinWidth="100"
                            Header="Barcode">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox
                                    Text="{Binding Path=DisplayedBarcode, Mode=OneWay}"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanUserEditBarcode}"
                                    IsReadOnly="True"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"/>             
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox
                                    Text="{Binding Path=InputBarcode, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
                                    IsEnabled="{Binding Path=CanUserEditBarcode}"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="{Binding Path=CanUserEditBarcode}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
```

`IsHitTestVisible="False"` and `IsReadOnly="True"` will hide the textbox in the cell template from keyboard events, while `IsEnabled = "{Binding Path=SomeBool}"` only influences the appearance as enabled or diabled textbox when not in editing mode.

In cases where it isn't important to keep the appearance of a textbox in a cell that isn't in editing mode, it's easiest to switch the textbox to a textblock.

Comment: Why do you have a `TextBox` in the `CellTemplate` instead of a `TextBlock`?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot. Changing TextBox to TextBlock in the CellTemplate solved my issue. Apparently, the TextBox in the CellTemplate masked the one in the CellEditingTemplate. Thank you!